# how can i add an if condition to my app in kivymd

Tags: python, user-interface, kivymd

So the main issue with this code is that yeah sure it works fine but only displays onto the console instead of the kivy app.

```
    def my_func(self):
        open_p = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.op.text
        volume = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.vl.text
        hi = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.hi.text
        lo = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.lo.text
        model = pickle.load(open('ustech_model', 'rb'))
        input_dt = (open_p, volume, lo, hi)
        inpt_val = np.asarray(input_dt, dtype=float)
        reshape_vals = inpt_val.reshape(1, -1)
        anticipate = model.predict(reshape_vals)
        # return anticipate.round(2)
        if inpt_val[0] < anticipate:
            print(f"Buy!! & TP:{anticipate.round(2)}")
        else:
            print(f"Sell!! & TP:{anticipate.round(2)}")
```

how can i change the output to include the text i want to be displayed on my main application
here is the rest of the code:

```
import numpy as np
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
import pickle
import warnings

# warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category="FutureWarning")
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=UserWarning)

Window.size = (400, 600)

KV = """

MDScreenManager:
    HomeScreen:
    Main:

<HomeScreen>:
    name:'menu'
    MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
        text: "WELCOME"
        icon: "distribute-horizontal-center"
        line_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        font_size: 25
        # font_name: "branda.ttf"

    MDIconButton:
        icon: "location-enter"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.4}
        on_press: 
            root.manager.current = 'tab'
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
    MDLabel:
        text: "REMEMBER TO ALWAYS BE HUMBLE!!"
        halign: "center"
        pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.1}
        font_size: 12


<Main>:
    name: 'tab'

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "TRADEMAVERICKS"
            anchor_title: 'center'
            right_action_items:
                [["distribute-horizontal-center"]]


        MDTabs:
            id: tabs
            allow_stretch: 'True'
            on_tab_switch: root.on_tab_switch(*args)
        
            # NAS100
            Tab:
                title: "NAS100"
                MDGridLayout:
                    cols: 2
                    padding: dp(36)
                    spacing: dp(20)
                    MDTextField:
                        id: op
                        hint_text: "OPEN"
                        mode: "line"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .9}
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 150

                    MDTextField:
                        id: vl
                        hint_text: "VOLUME"
                        mode: "line"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 150

                    MDTextField:
                        id: lo
                        hint_text: "LOW"
                        mode: "line"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                        size_hint_x: None 
                        width: 150

                    MDTextField:
                        id: hi
                        hint_text: "HIGH"
                        mode: "line"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .3}
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 150
                        
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text: "SUBMIT"
                        on_release:  
                            app.func()
                            # if inpt_val[0] < anticipate:
                            #     print(f"Buy!! & TP:{anticipate.round(2)}")
                            # else:
                            #     print(f"Sell!! & TP:{anticipate.round(2)}")
                        
                
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "325dp", "150dp"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .32}
                    radius: 5
                    MDLabel:
                        text: ""
                        id: put_txt_here
                        halign: 'center'
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
                        
    

                MDIconButton:
                    icon: "home"
                    icon_size: "40"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .8, "center_y": .1}
                    on_press:
                        root.manager.current = 'menu'
                        root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                        
          
            # US30
            Tab:
                title: "US30"
                MDGridLayout:
                    cols: 2
                    padding: dp(36)
                    spacing: dp(20)
                    
                    MDTextField:
                        id: o
                        hint_text: "OPEN"
                        mode: "line"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .9}
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 150

                    MDTextField:
                        id: v
                        hint_text: "VOLUME"
                        mode: "line"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 150

                    MDTextField:
                        id: l
                        hint_text: "LOW"
                        mode: "line"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                        size_hint_x: None 
                        width: 150

                    MDTextField:
                        id: h
                        hint_text: "HIGH"
                        mode: "line"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .3}
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 150
                        
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text: "SUBMIT"
                        on_release:  
                            app.us30()
                        
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "325dp", "150dp"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .32}
                    radius: 5
                    MDLabel:
                        text: ""
                        id: put_us30
                        halign: 'center'
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}


                MDIconButton:
                    icon: "home"
                    icon_size: "40"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .8, "center_y": .1}
                    on_press:
                        root.manager.current = 'menu'
                        root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
           
            # GER30
            Tab:
                title: "GER30"
                MDGridLayout:
                    cols: 2
                    padding: dp(36)
                    spacing: dp(20)
                     
                    MDTextField:
                        id: op_1
                        hint_text: "OPEN"
                        mode: "line"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .9}
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 150

                    MDTextField:
                        id: vol_1
                        hint_text: "VOLUME"
                        mode: "line"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 150

                    MDTextField:
                        id: lo_1
                        hint_text: "LOW"
                        mode: "line"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                        size_hint_x: None 
                        width: 150

                    MDTextField:
                        id: hi_1
                        hint_text: "HIGH"
                        mode: "line"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .3}
                        size_hint_x: None
                        width: 150
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text: "SUBMIT"
                        on_release:  
                            app.ger30()
                            
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "325dp", "150dp"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .32}
                    radius: 5
                    MDLabel:
                        text: ""
                        id: put_ger30
                        halign: 'center'
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}


                MDIconButton:
                    icon: "home"
                    icon_size: "40"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .8, "center_y": .1}
                    on_press:
                        root.manager.current = 'menu'
                        root.manager.transition.direction = "right"


<Tab>:
    MDLabel:
        id: label
        halign: "center"

"""


class Tab(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass


class Main(Screen):
    def on_tab_switch(self, instance_tabs, instance_tab, instance_tab_label, tab_text):
        '''Called when switching tabs.

        :type instance_tabs: <kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabs object>;
        :param instance_tab: <main.Tab object>;
        :param instance_tab_label: <kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabsLabel object>;
        :param tab_text: text or name icon of tab;
        '''

    # instance_tab.ids.label.text = tab_text

    # 'Red', 'Pink', 'Purple', 'DeepPurple', 'Indigo', 'Blue', 'LightBlue', 'Cyan', 'Teal', 'Green',
    # 'LightGreen', 'Lime', 'Yellow', 'Amber', 'Orange', 'DeepOrange', 'Brown', 'Gray', 'BlueGray'


class TM(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Amber"
        self.icon = "logo.png"
        Builder.load_string(KV)

        sm = MDScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(Main(name='tab'))
        return sm

    # For NAS100
    def my_func(self):
        open_p = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.op.text
        volume = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.vl.text
        hi = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.hi.text
        lo = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.lo.text
        model = pickle.load(open('ustech_model', 'rb'))
        input_dt = (open_p, volume, lo, hi)
        inpt_val = np.asarray(input_dt, dtype=float)
        reshape_vals = inpt_val.reshape(1, -1)
        anticipate = model.predict(reshape_vals)
        # return anticipate.round(2)
        if inpt_val[0] < anticipate:
            print(f"Buy!! & TP:{anticipate.round(2)}")
        else:
            print(f"Sell!! & TP:{anticipate.round(2)}")

    def func(self):
        self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.put_txt_here.text = str(self.my_func())

    # For US30
    def my_us30(self):
        o = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.o.text
        v = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.v.text
        h = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.h.text
        l = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.l.text
        model = pickle.load(open('us30_model', 'rb'))
        input_dt = (o, v, h, l)
        inpt_val = np.asarray(input_dt, dtype=float)
        reshape_vals = inpt_val.reshape(1, -1)
        anticipate = model.predict(reshape_vals)
        return anticipate.round(2)
        # if inpt_val[0] < anticipate:
        #     print(f"Buy!! & TP:{anticipate.round(2)}")
        # else:
        #     print(f"Sell!! & TP:{anticipate.round(2)}")

    def us30(self):
        self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.put_us30.text = str(self.my_us30())

    #  For GER30
    def my_ger30(self):
        op_1 = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.op_1.text
        vol_1 = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.vol_1.text
        hi_1 = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.hi_1.text
        lo_1 = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.lo_1.text
        model = pickle.load(open('us30_model', 'rb'))
        input_dt = (op_1, vol_1, hi_1, lo_1)
        inpt_val = np.asarray(input_dt, dtype=float)
        reshape_vals = inpt_val.reshape(1, -1)
        anticipate = model.predict(reshape_vals)
        return anticipate.round(2)
        # if inpt_val[0] < anticipate:
        #     print(f"Buy!! & TP:{anticipate.round(2)}")
        # else:
        #     print(f"Sell!! & TP:{anticipate.round(2)}")

    def ger30(self):
        self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.put_ger30.text = str(self.my_ger30())


TM().run()
```

I tried to change the print to the use the id for the label but it threw an error that it couldnt be found in the function

Answer (score 0):

For `ger30`:

```
#  For GER30
def my_ger30(self):
    op_1 = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.op_1.text
    vol_1 = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.vol_1.text
    hi_1 = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.hi_1.text
    lo_1 = self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.lo_1.text
    model = pickle.load(open('us30_model', 'rb'))
    input_dt = (op_1, vol_1, hi_1, lo_1)
    inpt_val = np.asarray(input_dt, dtype=float)
    reshape_vals = inpt_val.reshape(1, -1)
    anticipate = model.predict(reshape_vals)
    if inpt_val[0] < anticipate:
        self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.put_ger30.text = f"Buy!! & TP:{anticipate.round(2)}"
    else:
        self.root.get_screen("tab").ids.put_ger30.text = f"Sell!! & TP:{anticipate.round(2)}"

def ger30(self):
    self.my_ger30()
```